# a array of php with multiple textboxes

Tags: php, javascript, html

basically i have a database, which contains a random amount of questions
i have then printed this out as a php table using a query. there is as many textboxes to input marks as there are questions in the database. 
I want to create an array of my inputted data and then update the database with the marks in.

Here is my code

```
                    echo "<table border = '0' cellpadding ='10px'>";
            echo "<tr>
                <td> Question <td>Mark</td><td>Criteria</td>
                <td>Feedback</td>
                </tr>";

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {   
                $question[]=$rows['question']; 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>". $row['question']. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" ."<input type = 'text' name = 'mark[]' size = '1' value = '0' id = 'mark'/>/". $row['maxMark'] . "</td>";
                $maxMark[] = $row['maxMark'];
                echo "<td>".$row['criteria']."</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<textarea name = 'feedback[]' id= 'feedback'>Enter Feedback here</textarea>". "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }

echo "</table>";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>";
```

I am not sure how to create the array, with the marks you input. please help. 
In short i want to populate an array with the marks i input

Comment: did you test your code? Isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather easy to be done. All you have to do is setting the attribute `name` of your input controls and add an index.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="name[0]" /><input type="text" name="mark[0]" />
<input type="text" name="name[1]" /><input type="text" name="mark[1]" />
```

The post (or get) data your script receives will then contain an array instead of a single variable.